# Creating or altering documents in a CouchDB validate method

Tags: couchdb

I need to implement unique constraints on different document properties and the main idea is to have one document with all values and when the user creates a new document I check document properties and save both documents in a validate method.

Is it possible to select or update other documents in a validate method or is it only *oldDoc* and *newDoc*?

Comment: This sounds almost like you'd have a relational data model that you're trying to handle with CouchDB. What exactly is the use case ?

Comment: CMDB with flexible schema which can be changed without developer. For example datacenter has list of hosts. Host has unique name and unique integer id. The main problem that document can have many unique fields and these fields can be changed so I can't put their value to id field.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [the Document Update Validation docs](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Validation) the only things passed to (ie. available in) a validate function are the old doc, new doc, the user context, and the security object of the DB.